# Show DIV at the bottom of another DIV without scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, css-position

I have 3 `div`s:

```
#statements {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  max-width: 340px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}  

#entries {
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  max-width: inherit;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#entryform {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  width: 340px;
}
```

I need it so that the `entries` and the `entryform` located inside the `statements` have the following positioning:

1. all the content inside `entryform` should always at the bottom of `statements`
2. `statements` is always the height of the browser window
3. `entries` is always scrollable `div` that is positionined at the top of `statements` and takes `60%` of space.

I tried with the code above and it doesn't really work.

```
<div id="statements">
  <div id="entries">entry</div>
  <div id="entryform">entryform</div>
</div>
```

[Click here for JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aseko6g6/)

As you can see above the content loads fine, but I have to scroll down the window with the results to see "entryform". Why? How can I fix that so that "entryform" shows at the bottom of the window without me having to scroll down?

**UPDATE** one solution could be to set `position: fixed` for the `entryform` element, but I can't do that because in my design there's a menu on the left and when the user opens it, the `statement` div and all the divs inside should move to the right. With `position: fixed` this doesn't happen, i.e. the `entryform` stays where it is.

Comment: You need `position: fixed;` rather than `position: absolute;`

Comment: I'd like to but I can't because there's a menu on the left that the user can open and it should move all the elements (`statement` and whatever is inside) to the right. If I make `position: fixed` for the `entryform` element it won't be moved by the menu.

Comment: like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/aseko6g6/2/

Comment: @charlietfl yes! so it was about removing `padding-bottom` thanks!

Comment: that and setting body to have no padding/margin and to be 100% height

Comment: @charlietfl you want to post the answer?

Comment: By the way this doesn't work on an iphone... @charlietfl

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of your description this is what you want...

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}    
#statements {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
      max-width: 340px;
      padding-left: 50px;
      z-index: 1;
      background: red;
    }  

    #entries {
      position: relative;
      height: 60%;
      max-width: inherit;
      overflow: scroll;
      background: green;
    }

    #entryform {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      width: 340px;
      background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div id="statements">
      <div id="entries">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer justo quam, venenatis et blandit et, varius id neque. Quisque laoreet justo justo, sed rhoncus nisl mollis sed. Nunc vitae interdum lacus. Aenean in justo orci. Vestibulum lobortis risus id tellus vehicula vestibulum. Praesent quis cursus ex, quis mollis diam. Nullam feugiat id sapien vel porta. Etiam elit diam, ultrices eu nisi sed, tempus varius erat. Duis aliquet mauris felis, id viverra est vulputate ut. Donec pharetra felis eu facilisis ornare. Aliquam ac justo vitae lacus tristique interdum non sollicitudin nunc. Maecenas tincidunt elit orci, et commodo est blandit a. Nunc lacinia, mauris et porttitor porttitor, libero tellus lobortis nunc, id cursus neque dui in tortor. In sed mi et augue pretium sollicitudin.
      </div>
      <div id="entryform">entryform</div>
    </div>
```

---

[JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/aseko6g6/1/)

Comment: Great, thanks! How is it that removing `padding-bottom` worked? I mean isn't the height of `statement` supposed not to be affected by that parameter?

Comment: Why would it not be effected?

Comment: By the way this doesn't work on an iphone... the lower div is outside of the frame

Comment: It works on my iPhone and iPad. [There was a bug with earlier versions of IOS and vh/vw (see "known issues")](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Answer (score 0):

The padding that you have on #statements is causing it's total height to be greater than that of the page.

The 'height: 100vh;' that you are using is setting the inner height of the statements element to match that of the viewport, and then the 'padding-bottom: 50px;' is being added to the total height of the element, causing it to be larger than the viewport.

You can either remove the padding from #statements or adjust the 'bottom' value on #entryform to raise it above the padding.